# Java project error

Tags: java, android

I get this error from Eclipse:

```
The constructor File(List<String>) is undefined
```

at this part of the code

```
 public void deleteFunction(int id){ 
         Toast.makeText(this, "Sters", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        File file = new File(path); 
         boolean deleted = file.delete();
        }
```

Comment: What is the path variable? Is it a List<String>? If so that's probably your problem.

Comment: @nick How can resolve that ?

Comment: There are a couple ways. If path is supposed to be a String then change its type to String. If it's supposed to be a List<String> then you would want something like File file = new File(path.get(0));

Comment: @nick thank now it work but i give another error... The value of the local variable deleted is not used I'm n00b at java.

Comment: That means exactly what it's saying. That the variable deleted is never used. You need to either use the variable somehow (ie to do some kind of checking for successful deletion), or just eliminate the variable all together. It's been a while since I've used java but I think that's the right path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because path is `ArrayList` and you will need to pass path of file from path ArrayList instead of whole ArrayList change your code as:

```
 public void deleteFunction(int id){ 
         //...
         if(id<path.size()){
          File file = new File(path.get(id)); 
          boolean deleted = file.delete();
         }
        }
```

Comment: the app dosen't crash but the file isn't deleted. In logcat i don't se any error.

Comment: Thak for help :) But you can help me with entire code ? I get this err <b>The value of the local variable deleted is not used</b>

Comment: @RaulPetrescu : i saw your previous code can u plz send me latest http://pastebin.com/YaQ35Lt8  class

Comment: I upload the source here. https://mega.co.nz/#!iFtVQSSD!czLAAEYV7gBGyoO0SZADuFDlvuFLLt3QHLG06B0t0wk

Comment: @RaulPetrescu : i mean post me link of latest class code then i will try to help u

Comment: @RaulPetrescu : you are adding to items in menu ok. can u plz make a print for item.getItemId() and check log what u are getting in log and tell me exactly what u want?

Comment: @RaulPetrescu : see [this](http://www.mikeplate.com/2010/01/21/show-a-context-menu-for-long-clicks-in-an-android-listview/) example may help u in solving current issue

Answer (score 1):

It simply means there's no `File` constructor taking a list of strings.

Comment: can you help me to make File constructor ?